# Fill Excel file with for loop

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I'm trying to fill an Excel file using a for loop, the logic for filling is to do it every 189 results, for Example:

> Fill from A1 to A189
>   Fill from B1 to B189

At the moment I have a code which works fine with first row A, but the problem is when I try it with B, C, D, etc.

This is my code:

```
'' I don't need first 4 results.
'' Total rows in this case is 569
For index as Integer = 5 To totalRows Step 1
    Dim column as Integer = 2

    '' var used to know if row is completed and change the ExcelProcess method
    If rowsCompleted = 1 Then

        '' realRows = 569 / 3 rounded down = 189
        '' Flag initial value = 5 and is used as a internal index value instead of index var at for loop.
        If flag <= realRows Then
            '' copy
            '' Excel Range = spreadsheet1.Cells(index, 7)
            '' paste
            '' Excel Range = spreadsheet2.Cells(8 * rowsCompleted - 6, index)


            flag = flag + 1
        Else
            '' copy
            '' Excel Range = spreadsheet1.Cells(index + 2, 7)

            flag = flag + 1

            '' paste
            '' Excel Range = spreadshee2.Cells(8 * rowsCompleted - 6, flag)
        End If
    Else
        rowsCompleted = rowsCompleted + 1
        flag = 5
    End If
Next
```

Debugging step by step I founded some important details.

First row contains 190 rows but the first one is not needed so I only need 189 rows and start on 5. second and third row contains 189 rows so there is no problem. Also I need to start on 5 row.

Also I found that with my code the first row ends fine on 190. second row must ends on 379 but I found that ends on 381 or 382. So I think that maybe the problem is with my for loop and index or flag vars.

Also I think that maybe the problem is with copy the value with this code:
`Excel Range = spreadsheet1.Cells(index + 2, 7)` because I'm adding + 2.

Comment: The destination file, you want all data in 1 col. right?

Comment: @alowflyingpig Hello, no... in spreadsheet1 I have info but in different rows and I want to pass it to spreadsheet2 in one row but differents columns, as you can see on for loop .Cells()... I'm gonna start pasting on 2,5 then 2,6, 2,7, 2,8, and it must ends on 2, 189, then code enter to else statment and now pasting starts on 10, 5, 10, 6, and must ends on 10, 189.

Comment: Do you mean 5,2 6,2? When specifying `cells` its row then col. thus `.Cells(5,2)` = `.Cells("B5")`

Comment: To understand your question, you want data in spreadsheet1 A1-A189 copied to spreadsheet2 B5 - B193, spreadsheet1 B1 - B189 to spreadsheet2 J5 - J193  etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to loop?

```
Range("A2:D189").Copy
spreadsheet2.range("A2").PasteSpecial xlpastevalues
```

It's not really very clear what you are trying to achieve at the start you say `Fill from A1 to A189 Fill from B1 to B189` but then you say for columns A to D which is fine.

The second block of text says

`First row contains 190 rows but the first one is not needed so I only need 189 rows and start on 5. second and third row contains 189 rows so there is no problem. Also I need to start on 5 row.`

`Also I found that with my code the first row ends fine on 190. second row must ends on 379 but I found that ends on 381 or 382. So I think that maybe the problem is with my for loop and index or flag vars.`

I am having a hard time digesting what you mean when you say First row contains 190 rows but first is not needed (I assume you want row 2 to 190?) but then you say that you need it to start on 5 row so I am not sure if you want it to be from row to or 5??

Then you say second row must end on 379 so that doesn't make much sense other than it's 190 doubled.

Can you give a clearer outline if what you want to achieve? what do range do you want to populate and where from?